# Is there a way to have spaces in f-string?

Tags: pandas, f-string

I am trying to get the index for a value in a specific column of my DF that is variable and must have spaces in it. I do not have control of the name of this column.
I'm using query with f-string. So lets say I have the following.

```
import pandas as pd
a= 'Jan'
b=str(2022)
title=a+' of '+b
df=pd.DataFrame({title:['Inducts', 'Valid Reads', 'No Reads'],'Monday':[100,90,10],'Tuesday':[110,77,33]})
PlaceinColumn=df.query('Title==Inducts').index.tolist()
print(PlaceinColumn[0])
```

When I run this I get the following syntax error:

```
Jan of 2022 ==BACKTICK_QUOTED_STRING_Valid_Reads
    ^
```

SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Looking into this further it seems I cannot have spaces when using F-string. Is there a way around this beside making a new df out of the title column with a different column name?

Comment: Which line throws the error?

Comment: Sorry I copied in the code I was troubleshooting with. I fixed it. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Don't understand where is the mistake ? and for the f string :

```
import pandas as pd
a= 'Jan'
b=str(2022)
title=f"{a} of {b}"
```

Comment: Sorry I had copied in the piece of code I used to verify where my error was instead of the one throwing the error. I fixed it.

Comment: @JennB could you close the question please and vote for something useful if you want thank you

Answer (score 0):

Check the doc of [`df.query`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.query.html)

> column names containing spaces or punctuations (besides underscores) or starting with digits must be surrounded by backticks.

```py
PlaceinColumn=df.query(f'`{title}`=="Inducts"').index.tolist()
```